# Context Pool: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am facing the following issue when i run multiple queries to de db. Using Adddbcontext works fine but when i use adddbcontextpool i have the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this
> context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused
> by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more
> information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913

on my startup i have this config.

```cs
services.AddDbContextPool<context>(options => 
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("context")));
```

and on my service i have the following line that is called multiple times.

```cs
var maxEffectiveDate = await context.Transactions.MaxAsync(x => x.EffectiveDate);
```

i am using EF core 3.1.9

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you think MaxAsync has something to do with it?

Comment: Usually you may have this error when forgot to put `await` in some other place or when using `Task.WhenAll`. Check your code accurately.  One DbContext per thread.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv how can i fix the issue when i use whenall?

Comment: Each task passed to `WhenAll` list should have it's own `DbContext`.